# BST in java using arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to write a binary search algorithm that searches and inserts into an array here is the code. What I did is the right moves 2 times the index and the left is 1. here is the code. I was also wondering if the search method is faster than a iterative loop that goes through the array one by one?

```
 public class BinaryTree {
    int root =0;
    int right = 2;
    int left = 1;
    int arr[];
    public void search(int arr[], int value){
        if(arr[right] == value){
            System.out.println("found");
            return;
        }
        if(arr[left] == value){
            System.out.println("found");
            return;
        }
        else{
            left+=1;
            right+=2;
        }

    }

    public void insert(int value, int arr[]) {
            this.arr = arr;

            if(arr[0]==0){
                arr[0] = value;
                root = arr[0];
                System.out.println(root);
            }

            if(value>root){
                if(arr[right]==0){
                 arr[right] = value;
                 right+=2;
                }

            }
            if(value<root){
                if(arr[left]==0){
                    arr[left] = value;
                    left+=1;
                    }else{
                        left+=1;
                    }
            }

    }
    public void printint(){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int tol[] = new int[9];
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
      tree.insert(4, tol);
        tree.insert(9,tol);
        tree.insert(9, tol);
        tree.insert(2, tol);
        tree.search(tol, 9);
        tree.printint();
    }

}
```

is this considered a Binary search tree?

Comment: It is not a tree, so it cannot be a binary search tree. It is presumably a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: If you're looking for critique on this fairly bad code, you should post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not here, unless you have a *specific* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a specific term for what you are trying to do.  The way you've currently implemented it, it will fail to insert when arr[left] or arr[right] is not 0.  You need to use some type of while loop to retry after you've incremented the indices.

The subsequent insert will work because you just incremented the left/right value, but it you are incrementing the values by the wrong amount and you'll start overwriting values.  You would need to increment to (index * 2) + 1 for left and (index * 2) + 2 for right.

The search would be faster in proportion to how "balanced" the tree is.  A totally unbalanced tree would not be faster, and a balanced tree would be ln(n) (I think).

```
left *= 2;
left += 1;

right *= 2;
right += 2;

index  depth element
0      0     ROOT
1      1     L1
2      1     R1
3      2     L1L2
4      2     L1R2
5      2     R1L2
6      2     R1R2
7      3     L1L2L3
8      3     L1L2R3
9      3     L1R2L3
10     3     L1R2R3
11     3     R1L2L3
12     3     R1L2R3
13     3     R1R2L3
14     3     R1R2R3
```